# How can I chain position animations using jQuery without introducing a delay between individual animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm using jQuery to create animations of an image object.  I would like the object to follow a square pattern based off points I have.  What I'm currently doing is having four animations, just going point to point and they have the same duration.  I want this to appear to be continuous, but there is a delay going from animation to animation.

Is there anyway to make it continuous as it goes from animation to animation and have no delay during the transitions?

Comment: Post some code, and It will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the default easing method in jQuery being `swing` not the more evenly paced `linear`. You should be able to change the easing to linear and get what you want:

```
$("#myImg").css({top: 0, left: 0})
           .animate({top:100, left: 0  }, 1000, 'linear')
           .animate({top:100, left: 100}, 1000, 'linear')
           .animate({top:0,   left: 100}, 1000, 'linear')
           .animate({top:0,   left: 0  }, 1000, 'linear');
```

Comment: My wife thanks you (so I can head to bed now).  I was looking at the easing methods and got side tracked on the plugins.  I had an idea it was something with that.